# Wolfram Exponential Fit not match as formulas

Tags: regression, wolfram-alpha

I am using WolframAlpha Exponential-Fit formulas to find equation of Exponential Regression

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html

but after implementation, I tested with a simple set x,y pair : [{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}]

My app result :

```
A = 1.59431... , B = 0.27465...
```

While WolframAlpha double check with calculation expression :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exponential+fit+%7B%7B1%2C2%7D%2C%7B3%2C4%7D%2C%7B5%2C6%7D%7D

have different results :

```
A = 1.75135 , B = 0.24929
```

I full checked my code and can make sure, I followed formulas from WolframAlpha

Someone can guide me what wrong I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal and classical situation. Say that your model is $$y=e^{a+b x}$$ This model is nonlinear with respect to its parameters but you can linearize it writing $$\log(y)=a+bx$$ which is linear. Applied to your data points, this leads to $$\log(y)=0.466441+0.274653 x$$ which corresponds to the minimization of the sum of squares on the  logarithms of $y$. If you use these values as starting guesses for the non linear fit, you obtain $$y=e^{0.560384+0.249292 x}$$ which corresponds to the minimization of the sum of squares on $y$ which can be very different.

What the document you refer to shows is how to do the first step. What Wolfram Alpha does corresponds to the second step **which is the correct one**.

If you compute the sum of squares on the $y$'s, the first model leads to $0.230271$ while the second model leads to $0.159576$ which is much better.

Comment: sorry, I edited my answer, the final answer slope and intercept name are A,B, I applied the clause "where B=b and A=exp(a)." to calculate back A and B from a,b. Isn't it correct ?

Comment: The MathWorld document you refer just linearize the model (first step of my answer); but this is not sufficient. However, it provides you good starting values for the second step which is what WA does.

Comment: could you please guide me some ref docs about : "...use these values as starting guesses for the non linear fit, you obtain...", I am a newbie of regression-math

Comment: I have to leave and will be back in three hours. I shall tell you more. Cheers.

Comment: Are you already familiar with linear regression ? Please, answer in order I know where to start.

Comment: No, I have known a little about linear regression via wolfram-alpha. Can we have a graph of learning keys, such as Regression : {Linear : {Form,Error...} ,Power,Exponential,...} . Anyway, I am waiting for your lessons .

Comment: OK. Try to go and read in Wikipedia "linear regression" and "multilinear regression" first and ring me back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14255/discussion-between-user125586-and-claude-leibovici)